# My app take so long to be uploaded in app bundles

Tags: android

I have uploaded my app in app bundles but it been 2 hours nothing happened is that normal please tell me?
I don't know what to do my app is about 1GB

Comment: Why it is about 1GB

Comment: It is just like that what is this question